# JQuery mobile, is there a way to prevent the SELECT box from becoming a dialog page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

SO I have a select box that I fill dynamically.  I discovered that once the SELECT gets longer than the page, it automatically becomes a dialog listview.... which is TERRIBLE!

When this happens, the page refreshes when the dialog is closed and my whole page starts over....

Has anyone experienced that and do you know how to shut it off?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the native look and feel?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

> **Native form elements & buttons** 
> Although the framework automatically enhances form elements and buttons into touch input
>   optimized controls to streamline development, it's easy to tell jQuery
>   Mobile to leave these elements alone so the standard, native control
>   can be used instead.
>
> Adding the `data-role="none"` attribute to any form or button element
>   tells the framework to not apply any enhanced styles or scripting. The
>   examples below all have this attribute in place to demonstrate the
>   effect. You may need to write custom styles to lay out your form
>   controls because we try to leave all the default styling intact.

Comment: great idea, thanks!  Ill check that out... now to find out what happens when I have a really long SELECT element in native format on the iPad... maybe a filtered list is a better idea... anyway THANKS!'