# jquery mobile, style select options

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for a web app. 
I would like to style `options` in `selects`, like inserting background colors and maybe images.
I am not really willing to use another element than select, because the app is based on those selects, and they are changed problematically.

Can you help ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that you can only change background color when using _native_ select. To add images and further modifications, you need to convert it into `ul` and options into `li` to apply classes.

Comment: The other issue you will run into is how iOS displays the options - it puts them into the iOS UI so styling there is off-limits to the frontend developer.

Comment: @Omar, thanks I used the native option, and it is what I was looking for. However, it is weird because I used native on a button and sometimes it opens a "dialog" and sometimes a jqm pop...How can I make it always open a "popup" ? it seems it is when the list in longer than the page, it displays it as an horrible "dialog" page...I think someone has had the same pb here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028438/jquery-mobile-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-select-box-from-becoming-a-dialog-p

Comment: @Louis as you said, it depends length of list and screen height. If you want to use a native selectmenu, remove `data-native-menu='false'`.

Comment: Ok sorry I was confused : I was using native selects, now, thanks to your input, I am using non-native customizable selects...which I like (because I can use css on them). But they display as 'dialogs' when the list is longer than the page instead of as 'popup'. And dialogs are ugly....so I am wondering if I can force a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
data-native-menu='false'
```

for the considered select allow Jquery Mobile to take control over the select options and displays is as a customizable `ul` list.